# Negative binomial -- IRR interpretation for predictors

Tags: predictive-models, negative-binomial-distribution, incidence-rate-ratio

I have a zero-inflated negative binomial model.  I have used incidence rate ratios and I'm trying to interpret the coefficients in relation to my predictors.  Most of my predictors are continuous variables of census data -- ie: % of the population that is Hispanic; % of the population less than age 18, etc.  I know that the IRR is normally interpreted as the rate ratio for a 1-unit increase in the independent variable, but what does this mean in terms of these continuous predictors  -- does this mean the IRR is the estimated rate ratio for a 1% increase in % Hispanic.  Is there a way I can scale this so it can be interpreted to be the estimated rate ratio for a 10% increase in the % Hispanic?  Also, one of my IRR's is 20.  Does that seem unusually high?

Comment: The last question cannot be answered without knowing more about your outcome and the predictors. A factor of 20 increase for 1 percentage point increase in X could make sense in some contexts. You might also find the second example useful: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/output/stata_nbreg_output.htm

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean the IRR is the estimated rate ratio for a 1% increase
>   in % Hispanic?

Yes.

> Is there a way I can scale this so it can be interpreted to be the
>   estimated rate ratio for a 10% increase in the % Hispanic?

Divide the variable by 10 before you run your regression.